# UPDATE statement takes too long

Tags: php, mysql, xml

Well I have this problem that I hoped someone could help me with:

So whats it about?

I have a developed PHP script that imports XML files from a folder in to a database.

XML file looks like this- [XML file](http://www.basket.ba/ksbih/xml/30/30_01.xml)

Basically script stores information from the XML file in to 5 tables, and that works correctly. 
But the problem is that my file does not contain ID information of players in the PLAYER object so after I import everything in to database I have to run this query:

```
  $sql = "SELECT igraci.ID, utakmice.Player_ID, utakmice.ID AS broj FROM igraci LEFT JOIN utakmice ON (igraci.Team_ID = utakmice.Team_ID) AND (igraci.Surname = utakmice.Lastname) AND (igraci.Name = utakmice.Firstname);";
$tabela = mysql_query($sql);

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabela);
$totalrow = mysql_num_rows($tabela);
$i=0;
do {
    $i++;
    $sql = "UPDATE utakmice SET Player_ID=" . $row['ID'] . " WHERE ID = " . $row['broj'] . "";
    echo $sql."<br>";
   mysql_query($sql);
} while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tabela));
```

Select statement is executed really fast and I have no problem with that but the UPDATE command is making the script timeout. 
I have tryed making the fields used in this QUERY indexes but that didn't help and as soon as I have more than 2200 rows the script fails.
The script was executing ok on older version of php but last month we had to upgrade to 5.3 and thats where the problem started. 
Is there any way that I can speed this UPDATE up?

PS: XML file is from FIBA live Cms system.

Comment: you can use `LIMIT 1` in update query if you have only one record for the `ID` in table. will reduce some sql execution time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it the php script timing out?

Do you need to do this as a SELECT followed by potentially a large number of updates?

Could you not just use a single UPDATE statement, something like this:-

```
UPDATE utakmice
INNER JOIN igraci
ON (igraci.Team_ID = utakmice.Team_ID) 
AND (igraci.Surname = utakmice.Lastname) 
AND (igraci.Name = utakmice.Firstname)
SET utakmice.Player_ID = igraci.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an `INDEX` on `utakmice.ID` to speed up the `WHERE` part.

If you're not sure about performance run:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM utakmice WHERE ID = [x]
```

See if it's using an index or doing a full table scan (index is good, table scan is slow)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting an index on `ID` you can try batching your updates like explained in [here](http://blog.bubble.ro/how-to-make-multiple-updates-using-a-single-query-in-mysql/).

You need to prepare a query by concatenating case-whens when neccessary. It's worth a try, but I haven't done any performance tests to see if it could give you a huge boost here.

In the end you'd get something like:

```
UPDATE utakmice SET title = CASE
    WHEN id = <your_first_broj_from_result> THEN <your_first_id_from_result> 
    WHEN id = <your_second_broj_from_result> THEN <your_second_id_from_result> 
    ...
END
WHERE id IN (<your_first_broj_from_result>, <your_second_broj_from_result>,...)
```